# jQuery slider does not appear unless screen is resized

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using a Jquery Slider called BXSLIDER inside a hidden DIV that slides open via jQuery. The problem is that the slider does not appear unless I resize my browser slightly.

I think this is because the slider javascript is loading before the div is open, so it is not finding the proper height/width dimensions until after I resize the browser.

Is there any work around for this?

Example is at:

**[Example](http://newsite.penroserealty.com/areas) Make sure to click Cambridge and then Shopping - Then Resize**

Comment: Why not just instance the slider when it's done becoming visible? Or call some type of update event to the slider? There's no workaround, it's a common "bug" that happens when widgets get instanced on invisible elements.

Answer (score 1):

Hide the div with visiblity:hidden or position it absolute outside the viewable area. Then the element is still rendered and the slider can initialize correct. I also recommend the Jquery plugin imagesLoaded (https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) that is very useful for checking if all images are fully loaded before any slider initilization.

Answer (score 0):

I known this is old, but it may help others in the future. I had a similar issue where a JS chart wasn't showing until I resized the window. What I did was wrap the initializer as a function and then call the function in the event handler (in my case it was a click on a button). It was weird to explain without details, but here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Perry_/N3fpz/) with it not working and this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Perry_/sW7Np/2/) has the fix.

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#chartdiv").toggle();
    makeChart();
});

function makeChart() {
     var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
         //all the stuff
     });
}
```